# Passing Mustache template data between views

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm using Mustache in combination with Jquery Mobile and I'm looking for a way to pass information from my template into different views here's an example of my code

```
var ppl={"ppl":[        
        {"title":"Man","description":"Vice President"},
        {"title":"Man2","description":"Vice President"},
        {"title":"Man3","description":"Vice President"}
]};
```

My template first outputs the all the titles inside of a link

```
{{ppl}}    
<a href="#vp_page">{{title}}</a>
{{/ppl}}
```

What I would like to do is when the user clicks the link they are shown the title and description of the individual person.  I've been appending data attributes to the anchor tag but I'm wondering if there's an elegant way of doing this using mustache?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do: when the user clicks on a person link, some JavaScript code (jQuery) will display a modal window that will show the title and the individual description of the person. This jQuery code has to fetch the individual description from the server, most likely using an AJAX call.
With this in mind:

Templates are not designed to contain logic or pass state. That makes the code hard to follow and maintain.

To pass state between views use:

- if the views are implemented using JavaScript use JavaScript variables, parameters in function calls, events whatever.
- if the views are implemented on the server side and you need to pass state across request you can use: the session if your state is simple and small, a DB column for more complicated state.

In your case, It seems to me, the server should be able to get the person's title when it fetches the individual person's description and to return one JSON object that contains both the the person's title and person's description so that the client can easily display it.

Hope this help.